# Android get Install referrer through chrome or any web browser

Tags: android, referrer

can anyone explain if there is any way to get the Referrer parameter value if user is redirecting to playstore on my App through mobile browser(specially chrome).

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is. Google Analytics for Android has the capability to track install referrals provided that the user downloaded via a trackable link.

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/campaigns

If you implement GA in your app and use their url builder you can easily generate a trackable link that you can post online or in advertisements.

For example: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.example.application&referrer=utm_source%3Dgoogle%26utm_medium%3Demail%26anid%3Dadmob

Comment: for this i need to integrate google analytic sdk first..right? Is there any other option other than to integrate SDK?

Comment: no. you need to add the google analytics package of google play services to your project for this to work

Comment: I appreciate your suggestion but my concerned is little bit different i have explained it in the comment section of above thread. Please check

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use Google Analytics you can also obtain the referrer manually.

After the installation of the app the system issues a Broadcast which you can receive with a custom `BroadcastReceiver`.

Broadcast Receiver:

```
public class InstallReferrerBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String installReferrer = intent.getStringExtra("referrer");
    }
}
```

Manifest Declaration:

```
<receiver
    android:name="yourpackage.InstallReferrerBroadcastReceiver"
    android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Comment: This is already implemented in my App and its working fine. But my requirement is to detect browser if my app is installed then it directly opens my app and i can receive the data through deep-link whatever may be shared on deep-link Intent and in case Intent unable to find my app package then it should redirect to play-store to install my package with some value on Referrer parameter. Still i am not able to find any solution to this. Any help

Comment: If I understand you correctly you want to pass a parameter to your app. If the app is installed it should open directly otherwise the play store page should open, is this correct? This would be a different question.
Have a look at following question whether it fits your needs: http://stackoverflow.com/q/28744167/5199788