# Deep linking doesn't work correctly in Android 7

Tags: android, deep-linking, android-7.1-nougat

I've encountered that links like:

```
intent://#Intent;scheme=somescheme;package=com.some.package;S.browser_fallback_url=market%3A%2F%2Fdetails?id=com.some.package;
```

do not work correctly in Android 7 (7.1.1) systems, while in previous versions they work as intended. By "do not work correctly" I mean that if we have a required app installed to open this link, then everything goes as it should and this app opens when we click this link. But when we don't have the required app, a correct redirect on the fallback url is not processed: we're getting on a search results page or a blank page with a message about an incorrect redirect in a web browser.

Trying to find out how to solve this problem (maybe just by modifying the deep link), any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: is it working on android previous version ? is it worked on marshmellow ?

Comment: Yes, it worked completely on the Marshmallow.

Comment: Are you using the same browser on both devices?

Comment: @SimonMarquis, yes. I think that Android has closed a fallback url feature because of lots of spamming apps with this function. As a workaround we can use another type of deep linking described in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28744167/android-deep-linking-use-the-same-link-for-the-app-and-the-play-store, which is equal in its functionality to mine described in the question. The only drawback of this method is the lack of redirects' support (the link can only be opened from the <a> tag) - that means we can't encode large amounts of data in the link to be fetched by the app.