# Android Deeplink with facebook not working - redirecting to play store instead of launching application

Tags: android, facebook, deep-linking, intentfilter

I am trying to deep link my application with facebook.
My App `Url` is `https:www.xyz.com/app`

**Below is my intent filter:**

```
<intent-filter android:label="@string/app_name">
<action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
<data android:scheme="https"
android:host="www.xyz.com"/>
</intent-filter>
```

I am posting a link in facebook, when someone click on the link, the link is getting redirected to Google play Store and asks the user to open the application if installed, instead of loading the class in which the intent filter is present.

`Activity` name has been specified in facebook developer account.

Please let me know what mistake am I doing.

Comment: Does this adb command opens your app? `adb shell am start "https://www.example.com/app"` (replace example by your domain name)

Comment: By the way, uri schemes must be followed by two slashes: `https: // www.xyz.com/app`

Comment: @SimonMarquis That is a typo, I have taken care of that in the application

Comment: if you want to go to /app you should add android:pathPrefix="/app" to your data section

Comment: @Rainmaker I have tried that but still got the same result

Comment: @SimonMarquis That command launches my app correctly

Answer (score 1):

### Manual Solution

You need to configure your website to handle [Facebook's App Links](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/applinks/add-to-content) (different from Android App Links). In order to do this you need to add the Facebook app link meta tags to the associated web page. You should also configure your app to handle URI schemes as well, although I think App Links should be fine.

```
<head>
...
     <meta property="al:android:url" content="sharesample://story/1234">
     <meta property="al:android:package" content="com.facebook.samples.sharesample">
     <meta property="al:android:app_name" content="ShareSample">
     <meta property="og:title" content="example page title" />
     <meta property="og:type" content="website" />
     ...
</head>
```

You will need to have these tags present on every one of your web pages that is associated with web content. You can then check to verify that your meta tags are being properly scraped by the Facebook app with using this curl command:

`curl -a "facebookexternalhit" https:www.xyz.com/app`

Will all of this configured, Facebook should properly deep link out of your app.

### More Robust Solution

[Branch](http://docs.branch.io) has a solution already configured in the links. When a Branch link is created with an associated `$fallback_url` and your app is authenticated with FB (you can find how to do this in the docs), Branch will insert the correct meta tags for you. I highly recommend using this SDK as it will save you a lot of pain and heartache in your future deep linking endeavors.

Comment: So i have to check on every page for the applink?