# Is it possible to check the moblie application is installed using java or javascript?

Tags: javascript, java, android, mobile, webview

I'm making a Web-view moblie application with java and javascript

What I want to do is 
when people click the download link, i want to check whether they have my application or not, so
if they have, i want to open the application and if not, open the playstore to download.

Comment: Where do you want to open the application from? Is it from other applications for example messaging applications?

Comment: yeah like when someone share the download link of my application in messaging applications or in sns or etc and then when people click the link i want to check whether they have it or not.

Comment: please check this link : https://stackoverflow.com/a/28792160/5815636