# iOS Deep linking: open app after installing from app store

Tags: ios, swift, deep-linking, firebase-dynamic-links, ios-universal-links

I am trying to implement a feature like in this question [Android Deep linking: Use the same link for the app and the play store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28744167/android-deep-linking-use-the-same-link-for-the-app-and-the-play-store) but for iOS app.
Currently, my app uses UniversalLink(example: https://www.example/com/code/000000), and if the app doesn't install server redirect to the App Store by link (https://apps.apple.com/us/app/instagram/id389801252 - for example)
but how then after installation open link inside the app?
From this info https://support.google.com/authorizedbuyers/answer/6167336?hl=en
I understand that need some reference like (https://apps.apple.com/us/app/instagram/id389801252?mt=000000) what is ?mt=0000 <- this is deep link or something else?

How to implement this algorithm [image]